# Replace and Rearrange string in javascript

Tags: javascript, rule-engine

I have an input string

```
this.name in ['Sachin','Rahul','Anil']
```

If I find " in " in the above string, I need to replace this as below

```
['Sachin','Rahul','Anil'].indexOf(this.name) > -1
```

Similarly, If I have an input string containing not in

```
this.name not in ['Sachin','Rahul','Anil']
```

If " not in " is found, I need to replace it as

```
['Sachin','Rahul','Anil'].indexOf(this.name)  < 0
```

Is it possible to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: `I need to replace this as below`, you're not replacing anything. You're testing if a name is in the array.

Comment: Your pseudo code doesn't provide a proper explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: You want to develop a language which needs to be parsed and executed by JS engine?

Comment: @gurvinder372 looks like Coffeescript

Answer (score 0):

I understood you want to transpile keyword `in` into something that you wrote and add a `not` keyword which will be corresponding to that expression.

So... you can't achieve it in pure browser js without using some string parsing technique.
But you can go on with transpilers (which can be programmable in js), for example babel. In google you want to search phase "transpiling custom js".
[Some article using babel](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2015/09/13/lets-create-a-babel-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

To test for existence and replace

```
var theArray = ['Sachin', 'Rahul', 'Anil'];
var searchForName = 'Rahul';
var indexOfName = theArray.indexOf(searchForName);
if (indexOfName > -1) {
   theArray[indexOfName] = 'Sahil'; // gives ['Sachin', 'Sahil', 'Anil']
}
```

To remove

```
var theArray = ['Sachin', 'Rahul', 'Anil'];
var searchForName = 'Rahul';
var indexOfName = theArray.indexOf(searchForName);
if (indexOfName > -1) {
   theArray.splice(indexOfName, 1); // gives ['Sachin', 'Anil']
}
```

Although as the others have alluded to, its difficult to understand your intent based off the question